# State Updating in catch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In compoenntDidMount lifecycle, I am fetching an API, getting data and catching the potential error.  I can get the data properly. However, In catching the error stage, I would like to update my state as well but so weird, I cannot.

In state I have an **isError** boolean. It is false by default. When I change the api url in fetch, I can see console.log message, but my isError is still false.

```
componentDidMount() {
        fetch(
            "url"
        )
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    data1: data.response.venues,
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setState({isError: true})
                console.log("bla bla", error)

            });
}
```

Comment: Could you post your entire component?

Comment: this.setState is asynchronous (or at least, it can be). There is no guarantee that the state has been set before moving onto the next line, so logging this.state won't give you an accurate picture. If you need to wait for the setState to complete, setState lets you pass in a callback function.

Comment: @NicholasTower doesn't make sense at all. There is no guarantee but I can get the values from the API like a charm! So ridiculous.

Comment: What i'm saying is, just because your log tells you that this.state.isError hasn't changed doesn't mean there's a problem. Does the render function get run some time after this.setState?

Comment: @NicholasTower In this case the async nature of setState should not matter, since it is logging the error returned from the promise. It would be better for OP to post a more complete code of the component.

Comment: They said they logged `isError` and it was false. They didn't show that in the code though (instead logging `error`), so some reading between the lines is required. I agree, we need more code.

Comment: I this looks fine, it's going to boil down to *where* you are checking state.

Comment: are you logging `this.state.isError` in the render?

Comment: I agree with @NicholasTower, setState IS asynchronous (it takes a callback as a second parameter). You may want to log your state in the render function

Comment: I am logging `this.state.isError` in the render and in catch. Doesn't matter always false

Comment: Btw thanks for negative points, I really appreciate negative points, if somebody wants to give more negative points, please feel free.

Answer (score 1):

[Nicholas Tower](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3794812/nicholas-tower)
is right i think.

First are you using `ES6` or `redux` ?

Secondly try to pass your api call into an async function.
Catch the call with `await` to avoid setState execution as nicholas said.

If you use redux call your api with an action is a better practice.
A little example here : https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions

maybe like that :

```html
{
  try {
    const ret = await my_action(*);
  }
  catch (error) {
    this.setState({
      isError: true,
      errorInState: error,
    });
  }
}
```

Sometimes the speed of execution surpasses some slower actions and creates creates incredible bugs.

Comment: It will not help at all. Thanks